# match multiple OR conditions in python 3 regex findall

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

In python 3:

This is the Office of Foreign Asset Control list where individuals' assets should be monitored

https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.csv

a lot of their data of births (the very last column, comma delimited) are like

```
DOB 23 Jun 1959; alt. DOB 23 Jun 1958
```

or

```
DOB 1959; alt. DOB 1958
```

I am trying to capture all the birthdates after the keyword "DOB" AND "alt. DOB" with the following codes:

```
   if len(x.split(';')) > 0:
        if len(re.findall('DOB (.*)', x.split(';')[0])) > 0:
            new = re.findall('DOB | alt. DOB (.*)', x.split(';')[0])[0]
            print(new)

            try:
                print(datetime.strptime(new, '%d %b %Y'))
                return datetime.strptime(new, '%d %b %Y')
            except:
                return None
```

But the codes only get the birthdate right after "DOB", but not include the date of birth after "alt. DOB". Wonder how could i do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `DOB` and use a capturing group for the date part. For the date part, the number of days and the month can be optional followed by matching 4 digits.

The date part pattern does not validate the date itself, it makes the match a bit more specific.

```
\bDOB ((?:(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) [A-Za-z]+ )?\d{4})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bDOB`  Match literally preceded by a word boundary
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) [A-Za-z]+`  Match a digit 1-31 and 1+ chars A-Za-z
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
  - `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `)\b` Close group 1 followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4fprIA/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w3JqJ2)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"\bDOB ((?:(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) [A-Za-z]+ )?\d{4})\b"
test_str = ("DOB 23 Jun 1959; alt. DOB 23 Jun 1958\n"
    "DOB 1959; alt. DOB 1958")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['23 Jun 1959', '23 Jun 1958', '1959', '1958']
```

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, if i would like to capture " DOB Jun 1958", how could i modify the regex?  Thanks.

Comment: "regex = r"\bDOB ((?:(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) ?:[A-Za-z]+ )?\d{4})\b"" This will only return ['1959', '1958'].

Comment: @Chubaka In that case you can make the digits part of the month optional https://regex101.com/r/yTzDmm/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?<=DOB\s)[\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*`

```
   (?<=DOB\s)  = Negative look-behind assertion. This matches string (which is to its right) only if the string preceded by letters DOB followed by a space
   [\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+]* = Match space followed by letters of numbers multiple times
```

Example:

```
items=['DOB 23 Jun 1959; alt. DOB 23 Jun 1958', 'DOB 1959; alt. DOB 1958']
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'(?<=DOB\s)[\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*',item))
```

**Output**

```
['23 Jun 1959', '23 Jun 1958']
['1959', '1958']
```